# How do I center an image thats duplicated on multiple x,y coordinates?

Tags: python, pygame

Sorry if the title is unclear I may not be describing it to the best of my abilities, hopefully seeing the code it will make more sense.
Basically, I'm trying to create my own Pacman game using the library pygame within python.
Doing so I created a map using multiple arrays something that looks like this

```
['x','x','x','x','x'],  
['x',' ',' ',' ',' '],  
['x',' ',' ',' ',' '],  
['x',' ',' ',' ',' '].
['x','x','x','x','x'],  
]
```

then I created a function to set all empty spots of my array to the image

```
def create_map(self):
     for row_index, row in enumerate(WORLD_MAP):
        for col_index, col in enumerate(row):
            x = col_index * TILESIZE
            y = row_index * TILESIZE
            if col == ' ':
                self.food = Food((x,y),[self.visible_sprites, self.obstacles_sprites])
```

Then I created a class

```
 class Food(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self,pos,groups):
            width = TILESIZE/3
            height = TILESIZE/3
            super().__init__(groups)
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images',   'circle.png')), (width, height))
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos).center
```

The problem with this is that when I run my program the circle.pngimage is set to the topleft x,y coordinate in each postion and changing topleft within
`self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos).center` to any other keyword does not center the image. I've tried switching it to most of them including center, bottomleft, topleft, etc..

So im trying to center each circle.png image to the center of each x,y coordinate within the array where col==''

Here is an image of the current result I am getting :
[food image appearing at the top left of each empty spot of the array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaFSr.png)

Comment: could you edit your question and format the code properly? you have all code in one line.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki sorry I was trying to fix It's my first time using stack overflow, I believe its all good now!

Answer (score 1):

`self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos).center` makes no sense at all, because `get_rect(topleft = pos).center` returns a tuple with the center of the rectangle and assigns that tuple to `self.rect`

You have to set the center of the rectangle:

```py
class Food(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos,groups):
        width = TILESIZE/3
        height = TILESIZE/3
        super().__init__(groups)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images',   'circle.png')), (width, height))
        center_x = pos[0] + TILESIZE // 2
        center_y = pos[1] + TILESIZE // 2
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (center_x, center_y))
```

`center` is a keyword argument of the function `get_rect`. The instruction

```py
self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (center_x, center_y))
```

does exactly the same as

```py
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
self.rect.center = (center_x, center_y)
```